# Applying Quality Models to an Angular Application

Tags: angular, architecture, software-quality

I need to analyze an Angular application architecture regarding coupling, cohesion and extensibility. Are there any specific quality models which can be applied to an angular application?

I looked into QMOOD quality metrics but I do not know if and how to apply these to an angular project